# Compare strings in C using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm taking a C course, and I am having a hard time figuring out the following exercise.

> Given 2 char pointers, the function should compare the strings pointed to by the pointers lexicographically (case sensitive). It should return a negative, 0 (zero), or positive integer value, if the first string is found to be, less than, equal to, or greater than the second string, respectively.

> For example: The (first) string "Fan" is less than the (second) string "Fun", therefore the function should return a negative integer value in this case.

> Please note: An uppercase letter is different from its lowercase letter ('A' != 'a').

---

I tried creating the sum of each string and then comparing them to see which one was bigger.
Here is the function I have written:

```c
int StringCompare(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int str1_sum = 0;
    int str2_sum = 0;

    while (*str1 != '\0')
    {
        str1_sum += *str1++;
        str1++;
    }

    while (*str2 != '\0')
    {
        str2_sum += *str2++;
        str2++;
    }

    if (str1_sum > str2_sum)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (str1_sum < str2_sum)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and I get the following error:

`` Running test: StringCompare("oeis03HWoLn\I7]JJ=7yCWei4H\SN7S", "BlA;Vx<2lYY6r`Mu0Z1bnXL\EMqRkau")  --  Failed ``

---

When I tried debugging it, it went just fine, I am not sure whether I missed something in the code or if I just didn't understand the exercise correctly.

Help would be appreciated!

---

Update:
I updated my code with the following:

```c
int StringCompare(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    
    while(*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0'){
        if(*str1 > *str2) {
            return 1;
        } else if(*str1 < *str2) {
            return -1;
        }
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    
    if(*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0'){
        return 0;
    } else if(*str1 == '\0'){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, now I receive the following error message:

```
Running test: StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")  --  Failed: Invalid memory reference
```

I also tried running the code Surge suggested below, but I received the same error as well.

Does anyone know what might be the reason?

---

Update 2:
Added the following verification:

`assert(str1 != NULL && str2 != NULL);`

It now works:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int StringCompare(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    assert(str1 != NULL && str2 != NULL);
    while(*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0'){
        
        
        if(*str1 > *str2) {
            return 1;
        } else if(*str1 < *str2) {
            return -1;
        }
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    
    if(*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0'){
        return 0;
    } else if(*str1 == '\0'){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare each character of the strings individually. I can come up with strings where the sums of the encoded values are equal even though the strings themselves aren't equal. For example `"AD"` and `"BC"`. Assuming ASCII those are `65 + 68` which is `133`, and `66 + 67` which is *also* `133`.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) about lexicographic order. It is **not** related to the "sum" of the characters.

Comment: You interpreted the exercise wrong. Lexicographical comparison doesn't check "total value" of elements. Instead, it compares paired elements one-by-one, and returns early on first mismatch. If two strings are of different length and common prefix is as long as the shortest of strings, the longer wins (because any char is greater than `\0`). Strings are equal iff they have the same length and all characters at same indexes are equal.

Comment: When you sort data alphabetically, you are performing a lexicographic comparison when you compare the strings to determine which order to put them in.

Comment: The way you do it will not work. Solutions for how to implement `strcmp` yourself has been posted 100 times before on SO, just look around a bit.

Comment: See [strcmp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp): `int StringCompare(const char *str1, const char *str2) {return strcmp(str1, str2);}`.

Comment: Note, though, that the "case sensitive" part of the problem statement " the function should compare the strings pointed to by the pointers lexicographically (case sensitive)" is confusing.  What does "case sensitive" mean here?  Are all upper-case letters to be considered as being before or after lower-case letters?  Where do non-letters fall in relation to upper- or lower-case letters?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Thanks for the clarification; I understand it now. I am facing another issue. If you want to take a look, I updated the question.

Comment: @nielsen, I am not supposed to use `strcmp`, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @wohlstad, Yes, I got it all wrong. Thanks for the source! I updated my question.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. First the call `StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")` does not result in "Failed: Invalid memory reference". See for instance https://ideone.com/OfEBU8 Further, it makes no sense that an `assert` makes it work. An assert doesn't fix anything. It catches errors.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, I agree with you, I also don't understand the logic behind it. It may have something to do with how they test cases in their environment. I can say that it gave the error without the `assert`, and that it worked with it. Both for my code and Surge code.

Comment: @SupportUkraine `StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")` does make sense if the test harness passes `NULL` to the function and relies on behavior such as `glibc` to not fail and print `(null)` when invoking UB by passing `NULL` to something like `printf()`.  Of course, expecting the student-written function to handle NULL input without explicit direction to do so seems asinine, especially when apparently implicitly relying on a non-standard extension to handle UB invoked by the test harness itself.

Comment: @ChenBr I do hope you're not being taught to use `assert` for run-time error checking.  `assert` is absolutely terrible for that.  First, if compiled with `NDEBUG` defined, it evaluates to a no-op.  That it and of itself makes `assert` much worse than completely useless for reliable error checking - you rely on it to work, but it can completely disappear.  Second, blowing up the entire process with an `abort()` is almost **never** the correct response to bad run-time data for any code, and it's **NEVER** the correct response for library code to decide for the caller that the process must die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments you received are correct, regarding the understanding of lexicographic ordering. For completeness, here's my solution with some testing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int StringCompare(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{

    while (*str1 == *str2)
    {
        if (*str1 == 0) return 0;
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return   (*(unsigned char *)str2 < *(unsigned char *)str1) 
           - (*(unsigned char *)str1 < *(unsigned char *)str2);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("\"AD\":\"BC\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("AD", "BC"));
    printf("\"Ab\":\"aa\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("Ab", "aa"));
    printf("\"xxx\":\"aa\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("xxx", "aa"));
    printf("\"\":\"aa\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("", "aa"));
    printf("\"a\":\"a\xd0\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("a", "a\xd0"));
    printf("\"\xee\":\"\xef\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("\xee", "\xef"));
    printf("\"\xd0\":\"\" -> %d\n", StringCompare("\xd0", ""));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope it helps. (Empty string is the lowest in the ordering.)

Update: A comment pointed out that you may also want to check for invalid inputs like `NULL`. Unfortunately, there is no natural way to order invalid inputs in relation to valid inputs. That's why the correct approach is to check the validity of inputs before they are passed to this comparator. Another approach would be to return a complex type (say `struct{int order_int; int error_flag;}`) that deals with non-results.

Update2: Thanks to @chux - Reinstate Monica, another edge case fix. Because `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on implementation, the comparison with 0 is affected. If an extended ASCII character is used, that will put the string before a shorter string (terminating with 0). Also needed to have the empty string `""` properly ordered in relation to all valid strings.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I tried running your code (which, by the way, is very clean and understandable), and I received the same error: `Running test: StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")  --  Failed: Invalid memory reference`. Any clue?

Comment: @ChenBr For me it works fine. I'm not sure what code you actually ran. If you clarify, I can help.

Comment: I tried writing my code, but even copying your code gave me this error. I will update my question with my code. Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you're using `char *` inputs. I see `"(null)"` and I wonder if you're doing the right function call... :D Ofc, the algorithm can be easily addapted to other types.

Comment: The code is running in the course environment, so I don't have any control over the function call. The environment is testing several cases. Using "null" might be their way of testing edge cases, but I have no idea how to approach it. Wouldn't "(null)" be the text null and not the actual null?

Comment: They may be passing strings as inputs. Try accessing elements with `[i]` and increment `i` rathen than accessing and incrementing pointers.

Comment: The instructions state the following: Do not use the Array Subscript operator ('[ ]'), use the Dereference Operator ('*'). So unfortunately, it's not the approach they want.

Comment: The updated code you posted works as intended when compiled stand-alone. Which means that your environment is not providing inputs as intended, or you have misinterpreted the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am clueless about why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Guessing from the test error message (`StringCompare("(null)", ...`), you need to check if any of the pointers are `NULL` in the begining of the function.

Comment: Ah, good point @wohlstad. I'm assuming the strings are valid. Not sure though what to return in a comparison with an invalid string...

Comment: +1. However - about the `NULL` issue: it is a matter of test definition that the OP needs to find out. E.g. you could determine that if any of the pointers are `NULL` then they are "smaller" than any other string (except if both are `NULL`). The OP also needs to clarify the requirement for case-sensitive comparison that doesn't fit with the lexicographic requirement.

Comment: @wohlstad In `StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")` there are no null pointers.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I thought that maybe `"(null)"` represents a NULL pointer test. But as I wrote it's just a guess (BTW - the update the OP added about adding the `assert` actually supports this guess).

Comment: @wohlstad Well, then the assert should rather be `assert(strcmp(str1, "(null)") != 0)` but it would be rather strange to call `strcmp` from inside a "homemade" stringcompare ;-) Anyway, it all makes no sense. An assert can't fix "a problem" so ....

Comment: @SupportUkraine I agree. And I have no idea how the assert fixed a problem (assuming it's a standard assert) ... as I said just did some guessing.

Comment: @Surge "Empty string is the lowest in the ordering" is not quite right.  Consider what happens when `char` is _signed_.

Comment: @Surge Nice code.

Answer (score 3):

Only for the pedantic:

[@Surge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77134745/2410359) well handles many strings. Yet since `char` may be *signed*, a string that begins with a negative `char` is lower than `""`.

Instead, do what `strcmp()` does, it compares strings as if they are `unsigned char` values, even if `char` is *signed*.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value) C23dr § 7.26.1 4

```
int StringCompareAlt(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
  const unsigned char *ustr1 = (const unsigned char *) str1;
  const unsigned char *ustr2 = (const unsigned char *) str2;
  while (*ustr1 == *ustr2 && *ustr1 != 0) {
    ustr1++;
    ustr2++;
  }

  return (*ustr1 > *ustr2) - (*ustr1 < *ustr2);
}
```

---

OP's `StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")` indicates a problem in the unposted calling code.

Comment: Thanks! You make a good point, and I've been tripped by the signedness of chars before. I'll update my answer.